# Get array variables

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I got `serialize($result->response)` string that is saving to file, but I need variables from it, how can I access them?
I tried f.ex:

```
$result->response['StatusCode']
$result->response[StatusCode]
```

olso with uncase letters

But it's not working

I'm saving it to file like  this

> write_to_file("debug.txt", "order details: \n\n " .
>   serialize($result->response) . "\n\n");

And in file is this:

> a:1:{s:8:"OpenPayU";a:2:{s:14:"HeaderResponse";a:3:{s:10:"SenderName";s:8:"checkout";s:7:"Version";s:3:"1.0";s:9:"Algorithm";s:3:"MD5";}s:19:"OrderDomainResponse";a:1:{s:21:"OrderRetrieveResponse";a:10:{s:5:"ResId";s:32:"31cc3099884b92879ca144c5048ad07f";s:6:"Status";a:1:{s:10:"StatusCode";s:16:"OPENPAYU_SUCCESS";}s:13:"MerchantPosId";s:5:"37857";s:9:"SessionId";s:32:"77bd6bf3a1f029e250dbdccd59348bcc";s:14:"CustomerRecord";a:6:{s:10:"CustomerId";s:8:"nyi3iw6v";s:5:"Email";s:28:"meil@meil.com.pl";s:5:"Phone";s:15:"(+48)
>   786265656";s:9:"FirstName";s:5:"mieta";s:8:"LastName";s:5:"mieta";s:8:"Language";s:2:"pl";}s:11:"OrderStatus";s:21:"ORDER_STATUS_COMPLETE";s:13:"PaymentStatus";s:18:"PAYMENT_STATUS_END";s:10:"PaidAmount";s:4:"3000";s:12:"CurrencyCode";s:3:"PLN";s:7:"PayType";s:1:"t";}}}}

Comment: Are you working with the serialized value?

Comment: You need to unserialise the data first - use `unserialize()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on the data. It looks like your serialized string made an array, not an object. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

They don't finish explaining.

After you [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) an array and you store it someplace, and then you want use it, you have to [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize) to make it array again

so it would be

```
$file = file_get_contents('debug.txt');
$array = unserialize($file);
echo $array['StatusCode'];
```